# Mysql how to insert polygon

Tags: mysql, sql, geometry, polygon

I need to keep data about certain polygons in my MySql db. This is what I've tried:

```
SET @g = 'POLYGON((-74.13591384887695 40.93750722242824,-74.13522720336914 
40.929726129575016,-74.15102005004883 40.9329683629703,-74.14329528808594 
40.94256444133327,-74.13591384887695 40.93750722242824)))';

INSERT INTO buildings (name,num_of_levels,polygon) 
VALUES ('Bemax',7, geomfromtext(@g));
```

I receive an error:

> FUNCTION nekretnine_db.geomfromtext does not exist

When I try `VALUES ('Bemax',7, polyfromtext(@g));`

I receive same error:

> FUNCTION nekretnine_db.polyfromtext does not exist

Comment: Have you checked https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453084/inserting-coordinates-into-mysql-polyfromtext-sql-syntax-error-returning-nul

Comment: [Spatial Function Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-function-reference.html); [Functions That Create Geometry Values from WKT Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-wkt-functions.html).